# Stop Ruby - jRuby - thread after a certain time

Tags: ruby, multithreading, jruby

I'm trying to create a simple multithreaded program with jRuby. It needs to start and stop threads based on a specified amount of time e.g. run for five seconds then stop. I'm pretty new to this sort of stuff, so it's probably pretty basic but I can't get it to work.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
require 'java'
require 'timeout'
require './lib/t1.rb'
require './lib/t2.rb'

class Threads
  [...]

  def manage_threads
    thread2 = T2.new
    # Wait for 5 seconds before the thread starts running..
    thread2.run(wait_time = 5)

    Timeout::timeout(10) do
      thread1 = T1.new {}
    end
  end

class T1 < Thread  

  def initialize
    while super.status != "sleep"
      puts "Thread 1"      
      sleep(1)
    end
  end
end

class T2
  include java.lang.Runnable

  def run wait_time
    thread = Thread.new do
      sleep(wait_time)
      loop do
        puts "Thread 2"
        sleep(1)
      end
    end
  end

  def stop_thread(after_run_time)
    sleep(after_run_time)
  end
end
```

I have already tried a couple if things, for example:

```
# Used timeout 
Timeout::timeout(10) do
   thread1 = T1.new {}
end

# This kinda works, except that it terminates the program and therefore isn't the behavior 
# I want.
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to 1. start a thread, run it for a while. 2. Start a new thread, run both thread in parallel. 2. Stop thread 1 but keep running thread 2. Any tips/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it.

This did the trick:

```
def run wait_time
  thread = Thread.new do
    sleep(wait_time)
    second_counter = 0
    loop do
      puts "Thread 2"
      second_counter += 1
      if second_counter == 15
        sleep
      end
      sleep(1)
    end
  end
end
```